# How to use the getx builder to stream data from firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx, stream-builder

I am new to getX. I am trying to create a screen that displays some text from the firestore. To steam the data from the firestore, I use the GetX builder. So, I can constantly update the screen like a chat screen. The problem is the data is not getting updated automatically. When I add data to the firestore, I have to do a hot restart every time. So, the whole function runs again and fetches the data from the firestore.

**Controller class:**

```
 class StreamSample extends GetxController {
  List descriptionList = [].obs;
  getDescriptions() async {
    var doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Product Details")
        .doc("sample")
        .get();
    descriptionList = doc["description list"];
    update();
  }
}
```

**Stateless class:**

```
class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    // double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final sampleController = Get.put(
      StreamSample(),
    );
    sampleController.getDescriptions();
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: width * 0.08,
        title: const CommonText(
          text: "Home Page",
          textColor: kWhite,
          textSize: 1,
          boldText: false,
        ),
      ),
      body: GetX(
        init: sampleController,
        builder: (_) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: sampleController.descriptionList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return CommonText(
                  text: sampleController.descriptionList[index],
                  textColor: kWhite,
                  textSize: 1,
                  boldText: true);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
descriptionList = doc["description list"];
update();
```

Use:

```
descriptionList.assignAll(doc["description list"]);
```

Explanation:
Doing something like `descriptionList = doc["description list"];` updates the variable itself. Not the underlying stream it holds. To eliminate confusion and to be type-safe, you should declare `descriptionList` as final:

```
final descriptionList = <Type>[].obs;
```